# Simple Rock Paper Scissors game in Python

Tags: python, beginner, rock-paper-scissors

I am trying to write a simple rock paper scissors game in pycharm using classes and pygame. So far, I have not incorporated pygame yet. My idea is to import images that change in regards to the user's choice and the computer's random choice.

This is what I have so far:

```
import random


class RockPaperScissors:

    def __init__(self):

        self.wins = 0
        self.losses = 0
        self.ties = 0
        self.options = {'rock': 0, 'paper': 1, 'scissors': 2}

    def random_choice(self):
        return random.choice(list(self.options.keys()))

    def check(self, player, machine):

        result = (player - machine) % 3
        if result == 0:
            self.ties += 1
            print("It is a tie!")
        elif result == 1:
            self.wins += 1
            print("You win!")
        elif result == 2:
            self.losses += 1
            print("The machine wins! Do you wish to play again?")

    def score(self):

        print(f"You have {self.wins} wins, {self.losses} losses, and "
              f"{self.ties} ties.")

    def play(self):

        while True:
            user = input("What would you like to choose? (The choices are ROCK,PAPER,SCISSORS): ").lower()
            if user not in self.options.keys():
                print("Invalid input, try again!")
            else:

                machine_choice = self.random_choice()
                print(f"You've picked {user}, and the computer picked {machine_choice}.")
                self.check(self.options[user], self.options[machine_choice])

    def re_do(self):
        retry = input('Do you wish to play again? (y/n): ').lower()
        if retry == 'n':
            exit()
        elif retry == 'y':
            self.play()
        else:
            print("Invalid input")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = RockPaperScissors()
    while True:
        game.play()
        game.score()
        game.re_do()
```

In the future, I would like to convert this to use `pygame`.

Comment: Could you double check your indentation?  If you highlight everything and click `{}`, that should get you started.  Otherwise, your last few lines aren't rendering correctly.

Answer (score 3):

## Good things

You mostly follow PEP8 styling conventions, making your code quite readable. The only exception I see is an extra blank line at the beginning of the `score` and `play` methods.

Also, it is good thinking to wrap your game state into a class for future integration into a more complex project. It is also a good use of a main guard at the end.

However, there are things that need to be improved to reach your end goal.

## Things to improve

### Game loop logic

Your game loop logic fails completely: execution loops forever inside the `play()` method, and thus the `game.score()` and `game.re_do()` are never called. The game never ends and the total score is never diplayed.

You should remove one of the infinite loop, and handle it properly.

I would have a `run(self)` instance method that goes something like this:

```py
class RockPaperScissors

    # some stuff

    def run(self):
        play_again = True
        while play_again:
            player_move = get_player_input()
            machine_move = get_machine_input()
            winner = get_winner(player_move, machine_move)
            show_message(winner, score)
            play_again = get_yes_no_input()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = RockPaperScissors()
    game.run()
```

It still has some issues I'll address later (for later integration in a PyGame project), but at it should behave as expected potential issues can be worked on one at a time, in each of the method called.

### Separation of concern

Although you tried to separate logic (by implementing a game class) from display, you failed and mix both all over the code.

For example, the `check()` method should return the winner instead of displaying a message. Further down the line, if you want to implement a GUI with PyGame, you can handle a function return, or query the state of member variables, but a `print` output will be no use.

Same goes from getting input. Eventually, inputs will be supplied by a PyGame instance through widgets or something. You should put all console-related actions (`print` and `input`) in separate methods that you should be able to override, depending on how you want to use the game class.